# How to get hyperlink ids in another html file

Tags: javascript, html

am doing a project it requires a web site.on this site i have to darw state diagram for hyperlinks.that is how the hyperlinks are attached to one another on a site.am using html.how to get hyperlink id in another html file.i know about document.getElementById.
Thanks inadvance

Comment: Could we see what you have right now? This question is a bit vague.

Comment: I have to get o/p like a state chart diagram.if my site home page having 3 links 1)technology 2)contact us 3)privacy and again technology having 2 links 1)java 2)android . Then i should get o/p like a diagram ., first home page then 3 arrows that are linked to technology,contact us,privacy.and the technology will linked wit 2 arrows to java,android.

Comment: I dont know javascript thoroughly

Answer (score 0):

That would require a way to access another HTML file through AJAX, which is not possible if it isn't on your domain or if CORS isn't enabled.

There's however quite a few things you could do:

- Use your own server-side as proxy for fetching the HTML file.
- Do the processing on the server-side and let JavaScript plot the data.
- Do everything on the server-side.

If you'd like to get the ID's of a link you should use a HTML parser. Modern browsers include a such, it's called [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOMParser). You'd do something like this:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(yourHTMLSource, 'text/html');
var links = doc.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0, length = links.length; i < length; i++) {
  links[i].getAttribute('id'); // -> Returns the ID of the link, if any
}
```

As I remember it, IE doesn't support this, but has it's own module for HTML parsing with some different methods, but still relatively easy to use.